# How to start measure halfway?

Tags: lilypond

In my hymn, I need to start the first measure halfway through.  It has a time of 3/4, but I have to insert two empty, non-showing eighth notes.  How do I do that?

I've used `o4 o4 c8[ d]` below for the first measure, but lilypond does not like this.  What's the right way?

[image]

Here's the line:

```
o4 o4 c8[ d] e4 e4 e8[ f] g4 g4 f8[ e] d4 d4 g8[ f] e2
```

Comment: Hey, why the close vote?  There is a tag for lilypond, and they all revolve around using the lilypond code.  This is a coding question.

Comment: Some people are just close vote trigger happy and probably didn't bother to hover over the tag.  I'll admit it caught me off guard

Comment: Thanks for the confidence.  I looked, though, and there's only 4 questions that show when you click on the lilypond tag (but there are more than that if you browse)!  Maybe this isn't the right place for a question like this, but I don't know of a better one within Stack Exchange.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use a quarter-note rest?

Comment: I suppose there are more people that are familiar with lilypond at [music.stackexchange.com](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond)...

Comment: Ah!  I had no idea - thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Well, first I'm just getting started with lilypond and hadn't found the syntax for a rest, and second, I really want to start without one.  But tohuwawohu below has the answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **[upbeats](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#upbeats)**, there's a special command **`\partial`** available. In your case, you should notate a quarter partial:

```tex
\relative c' {
    \time 3/4
    \partial 4
    c8 d | e4 e4 e8 f | g4 g4 f8 e | d4 d4 g8 f | e2
}
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you.  I scoured the docs, but didn't know what this operation was called.  Now I know both how to render it *and* what it's called!