# Lyrics for additional verses in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond

Is there a way in LilyPond to simply list the lyrics corresponding to
additional verses after the end of the music, with one paragraph per verse?

(N.B. This exact question has been [asked before](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-music/2001-03/msg00089.html), in 2001, but the first answer ("read this book") references a dead URL, while the second (use `\context Lyrics`) does not work for me, I get LilyPond syntax errors.)

Here's a song under which I want to write the additional verses.

```lilypond
\header{
  title = "Hello World"
}

\score {
  \relative {
    \time 2/4
    \clef treble
    \key a \major
    cis''2 | a4 fis \bar "|."
  }
  \addlyrics { 
    He -- | llo world
  }
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}

\version "2.18.2"
```

(Sorry about the [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/178985), `<!-- language: lang-lilypond -->` is not yet supported in the Google Code Prettyfier that SO uses.)

I'd like to add verses 2, 3, and 4 underneath, separated from the music, just as words.

Comment: It'd be great to know why I got a down-vote so that I can improve the question

Comment: IMHO this is not a programming question suitable for SO but is a question on how to use a specific application. (and no, I didn't down vote)

Comment: But LilyPond is a programming language to produce engraved musical scores, and this is a question about how to use it. No? Andrew Cashner's comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30678473/575530) argues the case. But I'll [ask it on the other SE too](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/41122/2125) and see if that's more appropriate.

Comment: That's a big philosophical question.  But the more I think about it the more I agree with you.   I was going to say that this is the musical equivalent of asking what WordPerfect markup codes are needed to render a table, but when I thought `codes` and `render` I segued to HTML/CSS rendering which made my own argument moot!  I'm guessing that it is more of a familiarity issue of what is code and what is a compiler type thing (And I know all about of SO groupthink).  Perhaps you could recast your example with lyrics of `Hello World` - as what you have is not minimal as per Lilypond docs

Comment: Also you might be better off asking at http://tex.stackexchange.com  There are currently 51 Lilypond questions there

Comment: Brilliant - [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lilypond), [two](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond), [three](http://superuser.com/search?q=lilypond), and now [four](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) SEs. I'm often reminded that the most exciting work is at the intersection of things. LilyPond is certainly that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got an answer from [Knute Snortum](http://snortum.net/) on the LiliyPond mailing list [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.lilypond.general/109326)

After my `score` block I can add a `markup` block like this

```
\markup {
    \column {
        \line { \null }
        \line { 2. Here I go }
    }
}
```

It turns out that this is covered in the LilyPond documentation ([printing stanzas at the end](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/stanzas#printing-stanzas-at-the-end)) but they use the term 'stanza' and so my searching for 'verse' did not lead me there.

(It is also worth noting [this discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314849/575530). Posting LilyPond questions here is likely to lead to down-votes since it is not considered programming by many of the SO community. A better Stack Exchange site to post LilyPond questions to is the [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) Stack Exchange, though, as I found, the [LilyPond mailing list](http://www.lilypond.org/contact.html) is currently the place most likely to elicit full and prompt answers.)

Comment: I'm a former professional computer programmer and a current professional singer, LilyPond is absolutely a programming language, Not *general* purpose, of course, but within music, it is indeed general purpose, Sheesh.